# Fast Fourier Transform (fft) aggregation on Spark Dataframe groupby

Tags: numpy, pyspark

I am trying to get the fft over a window using numpy fft with spark dataframe like this:

```py
import numpy as np

df_grouped = df.groupBy(
    "id",
    "type",
    "mode",
    func.window("timestamp", "10 seconds", "5 seconds"),
).agg(
    percentile_approx("value", 0.25).alias("quantile_1(value)"),
    percentile_approx("magnitude", 0.25).alias("quantile_1(magnitude)"),
    percentile_approx("value", 0.5).alias("quantile_2(value)"),
    percentile_approx("magnitude", 0.5).alias("quantile_2(magnitude)"),
    percentile_approx("value", 0.75).alias("quantile_3(value)"),
    percentile_approx("magnitude", 0.75).alias("quantile_3(magnitude)"),
    avg("value"),
    avg("magnitude"),
    min("value"),
    min("magnitude"),
    max("value"),
    max("magnitude"),
    kurtosis("value"),
    kurtosis("magnitude"),
    var_samp("value"),
    var_samp("magnitude"),
    stddev_samp("value"),
    stddev_samp("magnitude"),
    np.fft.fft("value"),
    np.fft.fft("magnitude"),
    np.fft.rfft("value"),
    np.fft.rfft("magnitude"),
)
```

Every aggregation function works fine, however for the fft I get:

```
tuple index out of range
```

and I don't understand why. Do I need to do anything particular to the values in order for numpy fft to work? The values are all floats. When I `print` the column it looks like this:

```
[Row(value_0=6.247499942779541), Row(value_0=63.0), Row(value_0=54.54375076293945), Row(value_0=0.7088077664375305), Row(value_0=51.431251525878906), Row(value_0=0.09377499669790268), Row(value_0=0.09707500040531158), Row(value_0=6.308750152587891), Row(value_0=8.503950119018555), Row(value_0=295.8463134765625), Row(value_0=7.938048839569092), Row(value_0=8.503950119018555), Row(value_0=0.7090428471565247), Row(value_0=0.7169944643974304), Row(value_0=0.5659012794494629)]
```

I am guessing the spark row might be an issue, but I am unsure of how to convert it in this context.

Comment: can you add a sample input ? I think you cannot use `np.fft.fft` because it is not a spark function

Comment: also, can you add import ? we should be able to run your code and reproduce the error without asking for all the missing pieces. [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Added sample data and import.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`np.fft.fft` is a numpy function, not a pyspark function. Therefore, you cannot apply it directly to a dataframe.

Moreover, it takes as entry an array. `"value"` is a string. The function `fft` cannot infer that as being the aggregated list of the values of the column `"value"`. You have to do it manually.

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F, types as T

df_grouped = df.groupBy(
    "id",
    "type",
    "mode",
    func.window("timestamp", "10 seconds", "5 seconds"),
).agg(
    F.percentile_approx("value", 0.25).alias("quantile_1(value)"),
    ...,
    F.stddev_samp("magnitude"), # I replace the np.fft.fft with a collect_list
    F.collect_list("value").alias("values"),
    F.collect_list("magnitude").alias("magnitudes"),
)


#  Definition of the UDF fft. Do the same for rfft
@F.udf(T.ArrayType(T.FloatType()))
def fft_udf(array):
    return [float(x) for x in np.fft.fft(array)]

# Do that for all your columns.
df_grouped.withColumn("ftt_values", fft_udf(F.col("values")))
```